# Removing specific element from string but only in line that contains another specific element JS

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

Not sure if I phrase the question correctly so here is an example

```
let string = "Test text ab/c test
Test t/est
### Test/
Test t/test
Test test"
```

I'm looking to remove `/` from only line that contains `###` in it so it ends up like this:

```
Test text ab/c test
Test t/est
### Test
Test t/test
Test test
```

I assume I can use

```
mystring.replace(/\/g, '')
```

But how do I specify that it needs to remove `\` only in the line with `###`

Comment: Can there be more than one `/` on the line(s) with `###`? Should `###` be at the line start position? You have a typo, you must have meant `.replace(/\//g, '')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There is a possibility of more than one `/`. My goal is to make sure the line with `###` doesn't contain any `/` at all.

Comment: You can check if the string contains `###` and if it does, replace all the `/`

Comment: Or, use `string.replace(/(?<=###.*)\/|\/(?=.*###)/g, '')`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Its all one big string, so it always contains `###`, I need to replace `/` only in specific place.

Answer (score 3):

You can split on newlines and then join them back again.

```js
let string = `Test text ab/c test
Test t/est
### Test/
Test t/test
Test test
Test// ### test / 
`

const parts = string.split("\n")
  .map(s => s.includes("###") ? s.replace(/\//g, '') : s)
  .join("\n");
console.log(parts);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
string.replace(/(?<=###.*)\/|\/(?=.*###)/g, '')
```

The `(?<=###.*)\/|\/(?=.*###)` regex matches a `/` char that is either preceded with `###` and any zero or more non-line break chars, or followed with zero or more non-line break chars and then `###`.

See this JavaScript demo:

```js
let string = "Test text ab/c test\nTest t/est\n### /T/e/s/t/\nTest t/test\nTest test"
console.log(string.replace(/(?<=###.*)\/|\/(?=.*###)/g, ''))
```

Another solution: split the stirng into lines, then `map` the resulting array and remove all `/` chars in the items that `includes` the `###` substring, and then join the string back:

```js
let string = "Test text ab/c test\nTest t/est\n### /T/e/s/t/\nTest t/test\nTest test"
console.log( string.split("\n").map(line => line.indexOf('###') > -1 ? line.replace(/\//g, '') : line).join("\n") )
```

Comment: Lol, you have the same variant for the split (and earlier posted as well), my +1 for the lookaround solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

`.replace()` the whole segment then return everything *but* `\/` (the `\` is prefixed to `/` in order to escape it.

```js
const str = `
  Test text ab/c test
  Test t/est
  ### Test/
  Test t/test
  Test test`;

const rgx = /(###.+)\//gm;
const sub = `$1`;

console.log(str.replace(rgx, sub));
```